# prolog: issue with undirected graph: path to one direction works, but infinite loop for the other direction

Tags: prolog

I have this code given here:

```
edge(a,w).
edge(t,b).
edge(t,f).
edge(t,p).
edge(b,f).
edge(b,g).
edge(b,w).
edge(f,w).
edge(g,j).
edge(g,p).
edge(j,p).
edge(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X).
```

And I like to add some more lines to it (without changing the part above) so I can ask the program: "There is a path from node X to node Y?"

That's how I got it working with recursion, I add these lines to the codes

```
path(X,X).
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

Example, when I ask prolog if there is path from node `t` to node `w` e.g.

```
?- path(t,w).
```

prolog says: `true.` which is good. But when I want the other direction: `?- path(w,t).`
I'm in endless recursion loop and the program crashes and my computer is loud :/

I have tried to add some other lines to code but I cannot get it work. In the code above there is: `edge(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X).` but I don't know how I can add a good thing for this so it works all correctly?

Comment: Hint: If you add `edge(t,z).` at the top of your list of edges, your computer should also be loud :-)

Comment: you need to make sure that you are not endlessly revisiting the same nodes again and again. You could keep track of the visited nodes and make sure only to (figuratively speaking) step on a new node if you have not visited it before.